# Multiple custom post type and permalink issue

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have to declare two custom post type in my theme. But when declaring the second post type which is overwriting the permalink of first post type and rendering 404 error page :(

Please find my declartions below
Post type : Projects

```
$labels = array(
        'name' => __('Projects', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'singular_name' => __('Project', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'add_new' => _x('Add New project', ET_DOMAIN, ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New project', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'edit_item' => __('Edit project', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'new_item' => __('New project', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'view_item' => __('View project', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'search_items' => __('Search Projects', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'not_found' => __('No Projects found', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Projects found in Trash', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent project:', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'menu_name' => __('Projects', ET_DOMAIN) ,
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,

        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => ae_get_option('fre_project_archive', 'projects') ,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'project','with_front' => FALSE
        ) ,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'custom-fields',
            'trackbacks',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
            'page-attributes',
            'post-formats'
        )
    );
    register_post_type(PROJECT, $args);
```

Post type : Carry

```
$labels = array(
        'name' => __('Carry', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'singular_name' => __('Carry', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'add_new' => _x('Add New Carry', ET_DOMAIN, ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Carry', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'edit_item' => __('Edit carry', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'new_item' => __('New carry', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'view_item' => __('View carry', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'search_items' => __('Search carry', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'not_found' => __('No Projects found', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No carry found in Trash', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent carry:', ET_DOMAIN) ,
        'menu_name' => __('Carry', ET_DOMAIN) ,
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,

        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => ae_get_option('fre_carry_archive', 'carry') ,
        'query_var' => 'carry',
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => ae_get_option('fre_carry_slug', 'carry'),'with_front' => FALSE
        ) ,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'custom-fields',
            'trackbacks',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
            'page-attributes',
            'post-formats'
        )
    );
    register_post_type(CARRY, $args);
```

For all post under Carry and Projects type the permalink showing carry while changing the permalink to anyother from default structure.

Example:

Post title - "I am from Carry" under Carry type and "I am from Projects" under Projects type but URL will like  follows,

```
http://exaple.com/carry/i-am-from-carry
```

`http://exaple.com/carry/i-am-from-projects` instead of `http://exaple.com/projects/i-am-from-projects`

Please help me to identify the issue. Any help will be greatly appreaciated

Comment: You are using constants that are not defined in your code, like `PROJECT` or `CARRY' . What those constant are? Also, are you flushing the rewrite rules after the custom post types registration? One more note: custom post types shouldn't be registered by themes; better do it in plugins or you will loose data if you change theme.

Comment: PROJECT and CARRY used instead of projects and carry post type respectivly